# SQL datediff function data convertion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have calculated field in my query whereas it subtracts the days difference between two dates. I'm using SQL server to execute my query.

When I used the below function:

```
Cast(DATEDIFF(D,ACTUALFINISHDATE,PROJFINISHDATE) as int) AS 'Elasped Days
```

Both date fields are `datetime` date type (E.g `2019-02-23 00:00:00.000`). I have tried `Convert()` instead of `Cast()`, but still experienced the same issue.

I'm getting the below error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 7 The conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Do I need to convert the date time to `varchar` before converting?

Comment: Post some sample data.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: What is the datatype of `ACTUALFINISHDATE` and `PROJFINISHDAT` ?  It looks like its `VARCHAR`

Comment: @DigvijayS Both are datetime but contains null values

Comment: @Richard If both of those columns were datetime, that error would be impossible. Either you are focusing on the wrong code fragment or you have strings (varchar, nvarchar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have bad data, either in ActualFinishDate or ProjFinishDate.  To find the bad data...

```
Select ActualFinishDate
From YourTable
Where ActualFinishDate > '' 
      And IsDate(ActualFinishDate) = 0
```

Comment: It returns plenty of null rows. so for null values, I'd need to consider as 0?

Comment: Nulls are not your problem.  I modified the query to filter out the null values.  Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to convert the results to an int.  Just use:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, ACTUALFINISHDATE, PROJFINISHDATE)
```

Second, `DATEDIFF()` works fine on `datetime` data types.  So, there are two possibilities:

1. Your columns are not really `DATETIMEE`, but are strings instead.
2. Something else is generating the error.

I would guess (1).  You can test this by doing:

```
select ACTUALFINISHDATE, PROJFINISHDATE
from t
where try_convert(datetime, coalesce(ACTUALFINISHDATE, getdate())) is null or
      try_convert(datetime, coalesce(PROJFINISHDATE, getdate())) is null;
```

If the columns are filled with legitimate values, this will return no rows.

Comment: I have null values in both columns. would that cause this issue ?

Comment: @Richard . . . `NULL` values will not cause a type conversion issue.